# When I am in last Item In CardStackView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have  `RecyclerView`([CardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView)) With 60 items.

Now After finish All Items .. I have Blank Page .. I do not want to Show The blank Page if all items finished ... I want to Intent to Another Activity  You can see The blank Page [Here](https://giphy.com/gifs/8FfCeLBHj8j5RvS1gd)

when I implement `CardStackListener` I Added Those `Method` too Like This .I want to When All card Answered `Intent` To `ResultActivity`...Like [This](https://gifyu.com/image/TiFz) After 60th question I want InstedOf Blank Page Intent To `ResultActivity`

---

```
 //Card Method
  @Override
  public void onCardDragging(Direction direction, float ratio) {
    Log.d("CardStackView", "onCardDragging: d = " + direction.name() + ", r = " + ratio);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
    Log.d("CardStackView", "onCardSwiped: p = " + manager.getTopPosition() + ", d = " + direction);
    if (manager.getTopPosition() == mbtiQuestAdapter.getItemCount() - 5) {
      mbtiQuestAdapter.addQuestion(questions);
      mbtiQuestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    position++;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MbtiQuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    Log.i(TAG, "onResultClick: " + result);
    startActivity(intent);


  }

  @Override
  public void onCardRewound() {
    Log.d("CardStackView", "onCardRewound: " + manager.getTopPosition());
  }

  @Override
  public void onCardCanceled() {
    Log.d("CardStackView", "onCardCanceled:" + manager.getTopPosition());
  }
```

---

**Adapter.java**

```
public class MbtiQuestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MbtiQuestAdapter.MbtiQuestViewHolder> {


  private List<Question> questionList;
  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
  private final OnItemClickListener listener;


  private static final String TAG = "MbtiQuestAdapter";


  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, char value);
  }


  public MbtiQuestAdapter(List<Question> questionList, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.questionList = questionList;
    this.listener = listener;
  }


  @NonNull
  @Override
  public MbtiQuestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (layoutInflater == null) {
      layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    }

    MbtiItemRowBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater,
      R.layout.mbti_item_row, parent, false);


    return new MbtiQuestViewHolder(binding);
  }


  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MbtiQuestViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Question question = questionList.get(position);


    holder.binding.txtQuesNum.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

    holder.binding.txtQuesTitle.setText(question.getQuestion());
    holder.binding.firstQues.setText(question.getAnswers().get(0).getAnswer());
    holder.binding.secondQues.setText(question.getAnswers().get(1).getAnswer());


    holder.binding.firstQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(position, question.getAnswers().get(0).getValue());

      }
    });


    holder.binding.secondQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(position, question.getAnswers().get(1).getValue());
      }
    });


    holder.binding.setQuestion(question);
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    Log.i(TAG, " List Size : " + questionList.size());
    return questionList.size();
  }


  class MbtiQuestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private MbtiItemRowBinding binding;

    MbtiQuestViewHolder(MbtiItemRowBinding binding) {
      super(binding.getRoot());
      this.binding = binding;

    }
  }

  public void addQuestion(List<Question> questions) {
    this.questionList.addAll(questions);
  }
}
```

---

**SetUp CardStackView In Activity**

```
 //Swipe RecyclerView with CardStackView
    cardStackView = binding.cardStackView;
    manager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this);
    mbtiQuestAdapter = new MbtiQuestAdapter(questions, this);
    cardStackView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    cardStackView.setAdapter(mbtiQuestAdapter);
```

---

I want to Say If The items Finished Do SomeThing (Show Dialog or etc.)

Thank Guys

Comment: I Update My question when I implements CardStackListener and These is The Method plz See all of them

Answer (score 1):

#### Working Code

```
private CardStackView cardStackView;
private CardStackLayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // 
    layoutManager = new CardStackLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), this);
    cardStackView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //
}

@Override
public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
    if (layoutManager.getTopPosition() == adapter.getItemCount()) {
        // -------------------- last position reached, do something ---------------------
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

- You have `CardStackLayoutManager`. When card is swiped, callback comes in `onCardSwiped`.
- Here you will get top position (position displayed on top), and total item count.
- If `top_position == total_item_count`, then it is last position, now you can do anything.

#### Below is Output or same

[image: sc]

Answer (score 0):

Use `position` to check if you have arrived to last item. Inside `onBindViewHolder` method

```
if( position+ 1 == questionList.size()){
  // you are at the last item
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dear ...But Not work for me ...When I am in 57 item THe toast Show Not in after 60 ```if (position + 1 == questionList.size()) {
      Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "I am IN last ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }```

Comment: I want If all Card Finished And I are In blank Page The Dialog/Toast Show ...That means You Finished ...

Answer (score 0):

You ca try this by using scrollChangeListener like :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager.class.cast(recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    boolean endHasBeenReached = lastVisible + 5 >= totalItemCount;
    if (totalItemCount > 0 && endHasBeenReached) {
        //you have reached to the bottom of your recycler view
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Dear .. I have not RecyclerView .. And My app Crashed .. I have CardStackView ```java.lang.ClassCastException: com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackLayoutManager cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager``` the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Some code correction, it is better not to create listeners in `onBindViewHolder()` because it will be set each time this method called, better to set ones in **ViewHolder**

For example :

```
Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MbtiQuestViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.bind(questionList.get(position))
    }

class MbtiQuestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private MbtiItemRowBinding binding;

MbtiQuestViewHolder(MbtiItemRowBinding binding) {
    super(binding.getRoot());
    this.binding = binding;

    binding.firstQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), questionList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getAnswers().get(0).getValue());

        }
    });


    binding.secondQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), questionList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getAnswers().get(1).getValue());
        }
    });

}

public void bind(Question question){
    binding.txtQuesNum.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    binding.txtQuesTitle.setText(question.getQuestion());
    binding.firstQues.setText(question.getAnswers().get(0).getAnswer());
    binding.secondQues.setText(question.getAnswers().get(1).getAnswer());

    binding.setQuestion(question);
}

public void addQuestion(List<Question> questions) {
    this.questionList.addAll(questions);
}
```

}

Comment: @sana-ebadi I thought previous answer solved it, I am gonna take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

you could compare with `CardStackLayoutManager.getTopPosition()`, which should be the index position currently displayed. the [CardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView) GitHub  explains the methods which are available.

alternatively, just count the number of swipes:

```
int currentPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
    currentPosition++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. How Should use it dear ?

Comment: @sanaebadi added the comparison, too. just not certain if `.getTopPosition()` would return a zero or one based positional index... or in which direction the index is numbered. possibly the last one card could also be position `0` or `1` instead of the item count, depending on the direction.

Comment: ```if(manager.getItemCount()-1 == manager.getTopPosition()) {
      Toast.makeText(this, ";lkuygtfr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }``` like this ? in setup eight?

Comment: @sanaebadi how shall I know? which value does `CardStackLayoutManager.getTopPosition()` return, let's say for the first and the last one card? you may need to implement the `CardStackListener` in order to even get access to these event listeners.

Comment: dear return 0 ... I have 60 Item  ...```Log.i(TAG, "GetTopPosition: " + manager.getTopPosition());```

Comment: dear I implement it ... and I have ```onCardDragging``` , ```onCardSwiped```,```onCardRewound```,```onCardCanceled``` In my Activity ..I want If I am in the last item .. after 60th card Show Another Activity

Comment: @sanaebadi you'd need `onCardSwiped()` and a handle to the instance of the `CardStackLayoutManager`... the first and last card barely both would have position `0`, at least not within the scope of `onCardSwiped()`.

Comment: how ? ```@Override
  public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
    Log.d("CardStackView", "onCardSwiped: p = " + manager.getTopPosition() + ", d = " + direction);
    if (manager.getTopPosition() == mbtiQuestAdapter.getItemCount() - 5) {
      mbtiQuestAdapter.addQuestion(questions);
      mbtiQuestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }```

Comment: I have This code in this method , What do u mean dear ? plz help me

Comment: if `getTopPosition()` does not work ...you could simply add a counter variable `int position = 0;` and then increment it's value `onCardSwiped()` with `position++;`.

Comment: How dear? What the code should write in onCardSwiped() method?

Comment: just `position++;` while the variable needs to be defined outside of that scope.

Comment: ```int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
      position++;
      Intent intent = new Intent(MbtiQuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
      Log.i(TAG, "onResultClick: " + result);
      startActivity(intent);
    }``` I write like this .it os right ?

Comment: this is not what I've just wrote... while adding a bunch of useless complexity barely solves a problem.

Comment: I did not understand .. plz update your answer .. I want Intent To another activity ```position++;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MbtiQuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    Log.i(TAG, "onResultClick: " + result);
    startActivity(intent);```

Comment: This Code not worked for me :( ```@Override
  public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
    currentPosition++;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MbtiQuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    Log.i(TAG, "onResultClick: " + result);
    startActivity(intent);


  }```

Comment: please take a piece of paper and try to pen-test that code ...unless you wouldn't compare to the total item count - or with 5 as you've wrote it before, it will just increment the value and then start the activity, no matter what.

Comment: Mean dear? If u see the update And Gif https://gifyu.com/image/TiFz If I answer the 60th card I show the white page I want instead of Intent to another Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
//define the layoutmanager
private CardStackLayoutManager manager;

//make CardStackListener in layout manger and u need to implement methods 
manager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, new CardStackListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCardDragging(Direction direction, float ratio) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCardRewound() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCardCanceled() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCardAppeared(View view, int position) {
    //here if u print position you will find the position of your viewed item and this function will call when card viewed 
  }

  @Override
  public void onCardDisappeared(View view, int position) {
    Log.d("onCardDisappeared: ", "" + position);
    //here if u print position you will find the position of your Disappeared item and this function will call when card disappear 
  }
}
});

cardStackView.setLayoutManager(manager);
cardStackView.setAdapter(cardStackAdapter);
```